# What is the full list of punctuation and other symbols 'disallowed' from valid domain names under IDNA 2008?

Tags: unicode, dns, standards

So, according to **IDNA 2008** https://unicode.org/faq/idn.html

..the list of valid characters in domain names - while hugely expanded of late - still disallows "`.. full/half-width variants, symbols, and punctuation`"

But I just can't find that list. How can I find it out?

Just really need that list of disallowed character symbols.

I guess not 'pure' coding but if you can me help, you'll sure be helping me out with some coding stuff.. Tx!

Comment: I think you are looking on the wrong way; check the documentation where IDNA is defined and used. And from there look the allowed characters. Hints: the relavant RFC (so the "interned official documentation") are listed on bottom of relevant wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name

Comment: For the table see https://www.iana.org/assignments/idna-tables-12.0.0/idna-tables-12.0.0.xhtml#idna-tables-properties Note: it is not updated to Unicode 13 and 14